# Cake build NuGetPush throws permission denied

Tags: .net-core, travis-ci, cakebuild

I'm building my [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) app in [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) using [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/) script, when it comes to

```
var d = new DirectoryInfo(packageOutputPath.ToString());
var Files = d.GetFiles("*.nupkg").Select(x => new FilePath(x.FullName));

var key = EnvironmentVariable("NugetKey");

NuGetPush(Files, new NuGetPushSettings {
 Source = Variables.NugetSource,
 ApiKey = key
```

command I get:

```
An error occurred when executing task 'PushPackage'.
Error: One or more errors occurred. (Permission denied)
    Permission denied
```

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: required                

language: csharp              
mono: none                    
dotnet: 2.1.402               
before_install:
  - chmod +x build.sh         

script:
  - ./build.sh --Target="PushPackage"
```

I have tried replacing `- ./build.sh --Target="PushPackage"` with `- sudo bash build.sh --Target="PushPackage"` but this did not help. Any suggestions why I'm getting this error?

[build.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Carlj28/RickAndMorty.Net.Api/master/build.sh) file was builded according to [this](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/1751). Whole repo is [here.](https://github.com/Carlj28/RickAndMorty.Net.Api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `DotNetCoreNuGetPush` alias when using the .NET CLI, `NuGetPush` requires `nuget.exe`.

Example:

```
DirectoryPath packageOutputPath = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./nuget/"));

var settings = new DotNetCoreNuGetPushSettings
{
     Source = "https://www.example.com/nugetfeed",
     ApiKey = "4003d786-cc37-4004-bfdf-c4f3e8ef9b3a"
};

foreach(var file in GetFiles($"{packageOutputPath}/*.nupkg"))
{
    DotNetCoreNuGetPush(file.FullPath, settings);
}
```

Comment: Silly mistake! Thanks!